# Raising OnPropertyChanged when an object property is modified from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

So I have this object:

```
public class SomeObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public decimal AlertLevel {
            get {
                return alertLevel;
            }
            set {
                if(alertLevel == value) return;
                alertLevel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlertLevel");
            }

         private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

Suppose I am changing this object on a thread that is NOT the GUI thread. How can I have this object raise the PropertyChanged event on the same thread as the GUI when I don't have a reference to any GUI component in this class?

Comment: You have to use Dispatcher. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/change-wpf-controls-from-a-non-main-thread-using-dispatcher-invoke

Comment: Yeah, I saw similar ones but where is the Dispatcher class? Which reference do I need? I can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even better idea, **without using any WPF references:**

```
public class GUIThreadDispatcher {
        private static volatile GUIThreadDispatcher itsSingleton;
        private WeakReference itsDispatcher;

        private GUIThreadDispatcher() { }

        public static GUIThreadDispatcher Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (itsSingleton == null)
                    itsSingleton = new GUIThreadDispatcher();

                return itsSingleton;
            }
        }

        public void Init(Control ctrl) {
            itsDispatcher = new WeakReference(ctrl);
        }

        public void Invoke(Action method) {
            ExecuteAction((Control ctrl) => DoInGuiThread(ctrl, method, forceBeginInvoke: false));
        }

        public void BeginInvoke(Action method) {
            ExecuteAction((Control ctrl) => DoInGuiThread(ctrl, method, forceBeginInvoke: true));
        }

        private void ExecuteAction(Action<Control> action) {
            if (itsDispatcher.IsAlive) {
                var ctrl = itsDispatcher.Target as Control;
                if (ctrl != null) {
                    action(ctrl);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void DoInGuiThread(Control ctrl, Action action, bool forceBeginInvoke = false) {
            if (ctrl.InvokeRequired) {
                if (forceBeginInvoke)
                    ctrl.BeginInvoke(action);
                else
                    ctrl.Invoke(action);
            }
            else {
                action();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And initialize like this:

```
  private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     //setup the ability to use the GUI Thread when needed via a static reference
     GUIThreadDispatcher.Instance.Init(this);  
     ...
  }
```

And use like this:

```
public class SomeObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public decimal AlertLevel {
            get {
                return alertLevel;
            }
            set {
                if(alertLevel == value) return;
                alertLevel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlertLevel");
            }

          private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
              GUIThreadDispatcher.Instance.BeginInvoke(() => {
              if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                });
        }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Normally the event subscriber should be responsible for marshalling the calls to the UI thread if necessary.

But if the class in question is UI specific (a.k.a view model), as soon it is **created** on the UI thread, you can capture the `SynchronizationContext` and use it for raising the event like this:

```
public class SomeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SynchronizationContext syncContext;

    public SomeObject()
    {
        syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    private decimal alertLevel;

    public decimal AlertLevel
    {
        get { return alertLevel; }
        set
        {
            if (alertLevel == value) return;
            alertLevel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AlertLevel");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (syncContext != null)
                syncContext.Post(_ => handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)), null);
            else
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can pass `SynchronizationContext` via constructor.

Yet another way is to keep the object intact, but data bind to it via intermediate synchronized binding source as described here [Update elements in BindingSource via separate task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885552/update-elements-in-bindingsource-via-separate-task/32886415#32886415).

Comment: The problem with my class is that it is an element in a bindinglist. So the article you provide is very interesting.

Comment: This didn't sync in the first time I read it but I see it now. Posted an answer I ended up going with and now realize it is very similar to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

for WPF - Add the following references:

```
PresentationFramework.dll
WindowsBase.dll
```

In your background thread - wrap the code that needs access to UI into a dispatcher.Invoke()

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
...

//this is needed because Application.Current will be NULL for a WinForms application, since this is a WPF construct so you need this ugly hack
if (System.Windows.Application.Current  == null)
   new System.Windows.Application();

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
  //Do Your magic here 
}), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

for WinForms use

```
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => {
       //Do Your magic here
   }));
```

Comment: You need to add a refrence to `PresentationFramework.dll`, normally that is just used for WPF, but the dispatcher class works for both winforms and WPF.

Comment: Intelisense doesn't show it. Try pasting the code and compile.

Comment: very strange.. maybe You're calling it from unit tests ? is the application started ?

Comment: is it WPF of Winforms ?

Comment: This still doesn't work... I can see why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a clean implementation (relatively). Just had to include a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` which turns out to be a WPF library so eh..., not extremely pleased with it but it's a solution...:

```
 public class GUIThreadDispatcher {
        private static volatile GUIThreadDispatcher itsSingleton;
        private Dispatcher itsDispatcher;

        private GUIThreadDispatcher() { }
        public static GUIThreadDispatcher Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (itsSingleton == null)
                    itsSingleton = new GUIThreadDispatcher();

                return itsSingleton;
            }
        }

        public void Init() {
            itsDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }

        public object Invoke(Action method, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Render, params object[] args) {
           return itsDispatcher.Invoke(method, priority, args);
        }

        public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(Action method, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Render, params object[] args) {
            return itsDispatcher.BeginInvoke(method, priority, args);
        }
```

Then initialize it like this:

```
static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
           GUIThreadDispatcher.Instance.Init();  //setup the ability to use the GUI Thread when needed via a static reference
           Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
public class SomeObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public decimal AlertLevel {
            get {
                return alertLevel;
            }
            set {
                if(alertLevel == value) return;
                alertLevel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlertLevel");
            }

          private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
                GUIThreadDispatcher.Instance.BeginInvoke(() => {
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                });
        }}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure that `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` will have the correct value if you call it before `Application.Run(`.

Comment: It seems to work but I see what you mean. Should have probably initialized in the MainForm_Load...

Answer (score 0):

Found an even better answer **without having to use a WeakReference to the form control and NO WPF References** based on https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/01/23/synchronizing-calls-to-the-ui-in-a-multi-threaded-application/ and Ivan's answer above:

```
   public class GUIThreadDispatcher {
    private static volatile GUIThreadDispatcher itsSingleton;
    private SynchronizationContext itsSyncContext;

    private GUIThreadDispatcher() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// This needs to be called on the GUI Thread somewhere
    /// </summary>
    public void Init() {
        itsSyncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
    }

    public static GUIThreadDispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (itsSingleton == null)
                itsSingleton = new GUIThreadDispatcher();

            return itsSingleton;
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(Action method) {
        itsSyncContext.Send((state) => { method(); }, null);
    }

    public void BeginInvoke(Action method) {
        itsSyncContext.Post((state) => { method(); }, null);
    }
}
```

}

And initialize like this:

```
  private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     //setup the ability to use the GUI Thread when needed via a static reference
     GUIThreadDispatcher.Instance.Init();  
     ...
  }
```

And use like this:

```
public class SomeObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public decimal AlertLevel {
            get {
                return alertLevel;
            }
            set {
                if(alertLevel == value) return;
                alertLevel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlertLevel");
            }

          private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
                  GUIThreadDispatcher.Instance.BeginInvoke(() => {
                     if (PropertyChanged != null)
                          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                });
        }}
```