# How to update datatable which is datasource of a datagridview in multithreading environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I have 2 forms name Form1 and Form2.

I have a datatable in Form1, and I have a datagridview in Form2.

I have a problem when I update it in Form1 with `Task.Factory.StartNew` function.

when I add new row to datatable then datagridview will not be updated until I scroll it.
and
when I clear whole datatable  and add new row to datatable then datagridview still not changed and occur error when I sort by click one of columns.

first what is the right way to update datatable which is using in datagridview in multithreading env.
second, How can refresh populate datagridview after update datatable.

**Form1**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace dgvTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // DataTable for trade histories
        public static DataTable? TradeHistoryDT = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TradeHistoryDT = new DataTable();
            TradeHistoryDT.TableName = "TradeHistory";
            TradeHistoryDT.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
            TradeHistoryDT.Columns.Add("Side", typeof(string));
            TradeHistoryDT.Columns.Add("Ticker", typeof(string));
            TradeHistoryDT.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));
            TradeHistoryDT.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
        }


        public void add_rows_to_tt(int n)
        {
            List<Trade> new_trades = GenerateRandomTrades(n);
            ListToDT(new_trades);


        }

        public void change_whole_data(int n)
        {
            TradeHistoryDT.Clear();
            List<Trade> new_trades = GenerateRandomTrades(n);
            ListToDT(new_trades);
        }

        public void ListToDT(List<Trade> new_trades)
        {
            foreach (Trade t in new_trades)
            {
                TradeHistoryDT.Rows.Add(t.ExecuteTime, t.Side, t.Ticker, t.Price, t.Quantity);
            }

        }

        public static List<Trade> GenerateRandomTrades(int numberOfTrades)
        {

            Random random = new Random();
            List<Trade> trades = new List<Trade>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrades; i++)
            {
                Trade trade = new Trade
                {
                    ExecuteTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1 * random.Next(1, 100)),
                    Side = random.Next(2) == 0 ? "Buy" : "Sell",
                    Ticker = (TickerList)random.Next(1, Enum.GetValues(typeof(TickerList)).Length),
                    Price = random.Next(9000, 11000),
                    Quantity = random.Next(1, 50)
                };

                trades.Add(trade);
            }

            return trades;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => add_rows_to_tt(n));

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => change_whole_data(n));

        }



    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dgvTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Form1.TradeHistoryDT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the method executed on scroll?

Comment: @LajosArpad I modified scroll ==> click one column to sort

Comment: If the `DataTable` is bound to the UI then you must update it on the UI thread. You can execute a query to populate a new `DataTable` on a background thread, then merge that into the existing `DataTable` on the UI thread.

Comment: You did not answer my question. I wonder what is the method executed on scroll.

Comment: Instead of binding the grid directly to the table use a [derived](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32886415/5114784) `BindigSource` that marshals back every update to the UI thread. First, just use a regular `BindingSource` (can be added from the designer), set it as the source of the grid at design time, and set the binding source's `DataSource` in the code programmatically. When everything is fine (except the updates from other threads) you can create the derived class as per the linked answer.

Comment: You can't create, access, or update any UI control from any thread other than the main UI thread. You should also never do `Task.Factory.StartNew(` as a fire-and-forget method.